# React cargar datos sin recargar pagina

Tags: reactjs

estoy armando una tabla y estoy teniendo 2 problemas para cargar los datos, mi codigo funciona perfecto pero, una vez que aparece todo en el console.log tengo que ir a otra página y volver para que me muestre los datos... o en su defecto, tengo que usar el buscador para que me aparezcan los datos y los filtre, luego borrar el contenido del buscador para que me aparezca todo...

El siguiente error es que cuando quiero buscar algo y aun no se cargó la base de datos me tira error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')
```

Es bastante molesto ya que a veces tarda un poco en cargar la base de datos.

Mi código en data.js:

```
// ** Get initial Data
axios.get('http://url.com/api/customer').then(response => {
  data = response.data
  console.log(data)
})


// ** Table Adv Search Column
export const advSearchColumns = [
  {
    name: 'Imagen',
    sortable: true,
    selector: row => <img
    src={"http://url.com" + row.photo} alt={row.photo} width={50} height={50} />
    
  },
```

y este es mi componente TableAdvSearch.js:

```
const DataTableAdvSearch = () => {

  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false)
  const handleModal = () => setModal(!modal)
  // ** States
  const [Picker, setPicker] = useState('')
  const [searchPhoto, setSearchPhoto] = useState('')
  const [searchName, setSearchName] = useState('')
  const [searchDocument, setSearchDocument] = useState('')
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0)
  const [searchEmail, setSearchEmail] = useState('')
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([])

  // ** Function to handle Pagination
  const handlePagination = page => setCurrentPage(page.selected)

  // ** Table data to render
  const dataToRender = () => {
    if (
      searchName.length ||
      searchDocument.length ||
      searchEmail.length ||
      Picker.length
    ) {
      return filteredData
    } else {
      return data
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu código solo funciona cuando cambias de pantalla o buscas porque fuerzas el `rerender` del `componente`, es decir algo cambio dentro del componente, por lo que se debe rerenderizar. sin embargo aunque tu variable `data` cambie en tu `axios`, cambia tu variable, pero al no ser un elemento de tu componente, este no se rerenderiza.

lo que puedes hacer es pasar el data como `props`.

```
DataTableAdvSearch(props) => {
    ...
    const dataToRender = () => {
    if (...) {
        return filteredData
    } else {
      return props.data
    }
```

Entonces al cambiar data, al estar en `props` ya forma parte del `componente` y por lo tanto tu rerenderizado se activa.

La otra opción y que va más con los ciclos de vida de los componentes react es usar [useEffect](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), esto no solo ayudará a rerenderizar apropiadamente tu componente, sino que además ayudará con tu segundo problema, pues la barra de búsqueda no se mostrará hasta que tus datos estén cargados.

```
DataTableAdvSearch(props) => {
    ...
    const [dataTable] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://url.com/api/customer').then(response => {
            setDataTable(response.data)
            console.log(data)
        })
    }, []);
    const dataToRender = () => {
    if (...) {
        return filteredData
    } else {
      return dataTable
    }
    ...
    return(
        {dataTable
         ? <p> Cargando ..</p>
         :({'todo tu código de return aquí'})
        }
    )
```